# What are the parameters for Option in a dirmngr dialogue?

Tags: gnupg

I've connected to the dirmngr using the gpg-connect-agent. Typing help gives a list of options. Trying the `OPTION` command, I get : `argument required`

Trying `help OPTION` I get: `Not found <Dirmngr>`

What are the additional fields to the OPTION command?

Answer (score 0):

When running gpg in debug mode, the conversation with dirmngr is in the clear, so the `OPTION` verb is to set the different options for dirmngr, and not for retrieving the dirmngr configuration option itself.

for instance `OPTION http-proxy=http://237.237.237.237:237`

This wasn't displayed at first because dirmngr does a dns lookup for the keyserver to begin with and dies with a `No keyserver available` if it doesn't at least have an ip address associated with the keyserver.